# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having a code which inputs:

```
vgxgp
3
2 4
2 5
7 14
```

Expected output: `Yes No Yes`

1st input line contains a `string S`, the name of the item she is demanding.

2nd line contains an `integer Q`, the number of pairs of integers that used to say “Yes” or “No” to her.

These pairs are given in order, following Q line, each contains 2 integers, a and b. (1-based indexing) I am getting error at `if(line[a]==line[b])` as `ArrayIndex out of bound`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int t =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int[][] ar = new int[t][2];
        int k=0;

        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {       
            String[] input1=br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                ar[k][i]=Integer.parseInt(input1[i]);     
            }
            k=k+1;
        }
        k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(line[i]);    
            System.out.println(ar[k][0]);
            System.out.println(ar[k][1]);
            int a=ar[k][0];
            int b=ar[k][1];         
            System.out.println("hello"+line[i]);

            if(line[a]==line[b]) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
                k = k + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a bit of time to edit the code you've posted - the indentation is all over the place, making it *really* hard to read. Look at the preview before you post, and ask whether that's what you'd want to read if you were trying to answer the question.

Comment: Try to debug it you will find the issue .

Comment: Also, your variable `k` is never really necessary and can be replaced with the variable of the outer for loops.

Comment: @Mohit Darmwal Did one of the answers help you to solve your issue?

Comment: @MWiesner yes.. all the folks did helped me on my issue..thanks all

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by Niels Billen's answer your code uses wrong index positions for the array `line` as the length of this array is exactly `1` and thereby the index position to be used `0`. Using an index position of > `0` (given `a = 2` and `b = 4`) produces an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I have simplified your code in terms of readability, but due to a lack of a clear problem description I have just added a "good guess" which produces your desired output (Yes No Yes).

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int numberOfDataPairs = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int[][] dataPairs = new int[numberOfDataPairs][2];

        // read in the data pairs here
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfDataPairs; j++) {

            String[] input1 = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                dataPairs[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(input1[i]);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(line[0]);
        // compare the data now
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDataPairs; i++) {

            int a = dataPairs[i][0];
            int b = dataPairs[i][1];

            // produces your desired output... via a modulo (%) operator
            // but it's a guess - as description of the problem is unclear!
            if ((b % a) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Yes");

            } else
                System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got my mistake..using variable k in second loop is extra headache... but hlp me on ((b % a) == 0) how this comparing ??

Comment: see here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-mod.html - Again: most obviously this is not what you exactly want, I guess. Be more specific what the aim of your "comparison" is? In which case is the output YES and in which is it NO!?

Comment: @MWiesner...thanks man for the help..i want like if input string is coconut then if test cases are 2 then 2 inputs are like  2 3 & 4 5 .....then it should be comaparing string value at 2 & 3 i.e. o ad c if this is same the print YES otherwise O

Answer (score 1):

Your array `line` only has one element `vgxgp`.. That's why you get the error. In the final loop you are trying to access `line[a]==line[b]` where `a = 2`, `b=4`. These elements do not exist and will throw the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException